# Telerik Rad Grid Control PageSize Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using a RadGrid control with default PageSize as 15 .

When the user select page size 50 and click on next page  then how can I get this page size in .cs page?

If I use radgrid.Pagesize then it will take 15 every time.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Comments after this indicate there is a PageSizeChanged event.  Get the new page size there.


    
        protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged (object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Debug($"Grid page size changed to  {e.NewPageSize}");
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
protected void RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged(object source, GridPageChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    RadGrid1.PageIndexChanged = e.NewPageIndex; 

    Bind_RadGrid1(); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see this as wise given my comment above and this =>https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/simple-vs-advanced/defaultcs.aspx